# Does ORDER BY affect performance from within a joined view?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view, sql-order-by

I'm currently working on a project in mysql that uses certain views, there is a master view which joins these "subviews"

If I use `ORDER BY` in the subview, does it affect performance when I join this subview in the main view?

Or would it be better not to order anything in the subview, and only order in the main one?

Example of one of my SUB VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW `boletin_infoasuntos` AS 
SELECT 
    `bd`.`idBoletin`,
    `d`.`idAsunto`, 
    COUNT(`d`.`idAsunto`) AS `total` 
FROM 
    `tblboletin_declaracion` AS `bd`
    JOIN `tbldeclaracion` AS `d` USING(`idDeclaracion`)
GROUP BY 
    `bd`.`idBoletin`,
    `d`.`idAsunto`
ORDER BY 
    `bd`.`idBoletin` DESC;
```

Notice the `ORDER BY` usage.

And then it is joined from the main view.

Main VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW `boletin_actores` AS
SELECT 
    `bd`.`idBoletin`,
    `d`.*,
FROM 
    `tblboletin_declaracion` AS `bd`
    LEFT JOIN `declaraciones` AS `d` 
        ON `bd`.`idDeclaracion` = `d`.`idDeclaracion`
    LEFT JOIN `boletin_infoasuntos` AS `bia` 
        ON `bd`.`idBoletin` = `bia`.`idBoletin` 
ORDER BY 
    `bd`.`idBoletin` DESC,
    `bia`.`total` DESC, 
    `d`.`asunto` ASC;
```

What would you recommend? I'm for performance optimization, but the tests I perform show no noticeable difference in speed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In versions of MySQL 5+, the query execution-planning module is capable of deferring the ordering operations until as late as possible in query execution.  Therefore, in most cases what you're doing will perform very well. Wherever possible,  `ORDER BY` operations deep in the query will be ignored in favor of the outermost ones.

Still, many SQL application designers consider result-set ordering to be part of the presentation of data. That implies that ordering is to be done in the outerrmost query rather than in any view. If you were to follow that design principle, you would omit `ORDER BY` clauses from your view definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your second view has an ORDER BY with columns from multiple tables means that it has to create a temporary table with the results before it can sort it.

But views in MySQL usually create a temporary table anyway, so it's likely that you wouldn't see a great difference in performance.

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-algorithms.html for more details on temporary tables caused by views.